# Submit form and replace submit button with progress indicator

Tags: jquery, forms, click, submit

So we have a lot of forms around our website that unfortunately take a while to submit.

What I wanted to do was write a generic script that either on submit or onclick of a submit button would replace the submit button with a loading indicator and then submit the form, following any redirects that the form submission action does.

If I use jQuery to replace the button on form submission it doesn't replace the submission button but still submits the form. Decided to do it on .click() and that causes the loading indicator to replace the submission button but the form doesn't submit. Also tried to replace the submission button then put a setTimeout and cause the parent of the submission button to submit with the jQuery submit() function, all to no avail.

I've also gone down the road of AJAX submissions and so on but each presents it's own problem.

Currently my code is:

```
$("#content form :submit").click(function(data) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="loader.gif" alt="submitting form" style="display:block; margin:0 auto">');
    var form = $(this).parent("form");
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(form);
        form.submit();
    },1000);    
});
```

I know this current code is wrong but I've gone through so many different solutions that get it 90% that I've sort of lost it. Any suggestions on how to do this?

EDIT: Sorry I don't think this was obvious enough when I first submitted. On submission the DOM no longer gets updated on Safari at least. although the action happens the DOM doesn't get changed and the submission occurs. The result is the form submits as usual and the loading gif doesn't occur. I thought delaying the actual form submission until the DOM has been updated would fix it but it doesn't seem to submit (1000 is long but want to get things working first). Also if I place the listener on submit rather than click and try to call submit() in it  it will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the handler to the form's `submit` event, not a `click` event on the submit button:

```
$("#content form").submit(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('<img />', {
        'src': 'loader.gif',
        'alt': 'submitting form',
        'class': 'loading',
        'style': 'display: block; margin: 0 auto;' // Use a class instead
    }).appendTo(this);

    $this.find(':submit').hide();

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $this.attr('method') || 'get',
        url: $this.attr('action') || window.location,
        data: $this.serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
            $(this).find(':submit').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: seems recursive calling `submit` and `preventDefault()` within same `submit` handler

Comment: Why use a timeout? Also, `event` should be `e` based on your params.

Comment: @charlietfl: Fixed. Calling `submit()` on the jQuery object triggers the `submit` handler, but calling `submit()` on the DOM object does not: http://jsfiddle.net/kTt2T/1/

Comment: I was thinking same... using jQuery method only, would have never submitted me thinks

Comment: Updated question to better explain why there is a delay.

Comment: Working through this, it's actually very close to my original ajax thing but might actually work for that last 10%.

Comment: This works for me but I had other issues not relating to this problem so marking it correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could just hide the submit input instead of removing it. Seems to me much cleaner than using timeouts and things like that.

```
​$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    var submitButton = $(this).find('input[type=submit]');
    $(this).append('<span>submitting...</span>');//Replace with whatever you want
    submitButton.css('display', 'none');
});​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7GgU/

Comment: This is what I originally had but the submission causes the DOM (at least on Safari) to stop updating. If I return false it works as expected except of course it doesn't submit.

Comment: It works for me, even in Safari. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: I've tested it again and it doesn't work for me. What Safari you using? Firefox works but I suspect Chrome would be the same.